# Length of wire from one end only

Tags: arduino, wire

I'm looking to try and get guitar notes played in real time. My q is whether it's possible to do this from one end of the string to minimize adding stuff onto the guitar. If this is possible with an arduino that would be ideal.

Lisa

Comment: Whats wrong with using a microphone?

Comment: Good luck trying to evaluate the played noted in real time.  If you are using anything (like a microphone or pickup) that gets the sound from all strings at once then you have a DSP nightmare (been there, haven't gotten out yet.)  If you are picking up from each string independantly, then the DSP part is easier but you have to install 6 somethings onto the guitar to pick up the signal.  I've been working on a system using a microphone and DSP off and on for a LONG time, and not got anywhere near finished or accurate.

Comment: My thinking at the moment has altered to useing 6 piezo "pads" at the headstock and "teaching" software each note. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to get guitar notes played in real time - and you'd like to use an Arduino.

Here is a project where I used the Lorentz force to get guitar notes played...

http://wp.josh.com/2015/07/28/self-strumming-ghost-guitar/

I have successfully used an Arduino to control the strings by using a large MOSFETs connected to the Arduino digital outputs.

To minimize attaching stuff to the guitar, you can electrically connect all of the strings together at the bottom so individual connections are only require at the top by the pegs.

Comment: Hi... Nice demo but I want to go the other way... always against the stream!!!! hehehe... See my answer to Plasma HH.

Comment: In that case, I think you want this..
http://www.plaindsp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've got an old guitar that I experiment with now and then. It has a bridge pickup (i.e. at one end) that I rewired with 6 miniature magnetic sensors (magnet and coil of wire). There is a little cross talk with adjacent strings but generally it works fine and produces 6 signals.

I currently have the 6 signals going thru comparators to produce square waves then sum the 6 square waves. My old guitar now sounds a bit like a basic organ. I did this to overcome the nasty effects when playing complex chords thru a distortion (fuzz) box. It was just an experiment to get something a bit different and I'm planning to record with it soon.

Good luck, sounds an interesting project - I started mine in 1983 and it's still ongoing!

I really think that if you want to have success at this you use an electric guitar and rework one of the pups as I did. I used sensors that look like these: -

[image]

I believe the diameter is 1/4" - it's also worth noting that at the bridge end of a guitar the strings are spaced further apart and this helps to minimize crosstalk and gives slightly more space to fit things.

Comment: See my answer to PlasmaHH.

Comment: Good points... please see my reply to PLasmaHH. What do you think?

Comment: Well, my system works so if you want to try something new you can't say I didn't tell you.